# Product does not show on Magento2 categroy page

Tags: magento2

My Product does not show on Magento2 category page.My category page show blank .

any body help me.

[image]

Comment: run reindex command after check it

Comment: already done reindex

Comment: and set developer mode and check error logs

Comment: hey so share me your code and URL, please

Comment: As I have seen the link which you have shared, you didn't assign products to particular category please check it once weather have you assign products to category and check have you assign  products to the website also by using update attributes in admin

Comment: i have assigned  the product ,every categroy contain the products ,but it does not show on category page

Comment: product is enable and check status ?

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Vnecoms\VendorsProduct\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\DataProvider\Interceptor